# postgres "Returns Table" returns a string

Tags: postgresql

I am using the SQL language on Postgres to return a table using the RETURNS TABLE command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION procreadbudget()
  RETURNS TABLE(budgetmonth character, budgetincome numeric, budgetexpense numeric) AS
$BODY$
SELECT budget_month, budget_income, budget_expense FROM budget ORDER BY unique_id;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE
```

All the data is returned as a comma delimited string, not as a table:

```
"(Jan,1123,1201)"
"(Feb,1098,996)"
"(Mar,1545,1345)"
"(Apr,1564,1952)"
"(May,1123,990)"
"(Jun,1345,1234)"
"(Jul,1234,878)"
"(Aug,1139,1187)"
"(Sep,1076,1123)"
"(Oct,873,956)"
"(Nov,1298,1423)"
"(Dec,1123,1324)"
```

Any suggestions please,
Mike

Comment: So the question is, what do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM procreadbudget();
```

instead of

```
SELECT procreadbudget();
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
select t.budgetmont,
       t.budgetincome,
       t.budgetexpense
from procreadbudget() as t
```